# Sitecore using multiple IIS Websites configured with same physical path

Tags: multisite, iis, multitenancy

We have a multiple sites Sitecore instance at our client.  The architect is attempting to reconfigure that each sub-site has a dedicated IIS Website pointing to one physical path where the instance is installed, `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecore\website`.

Does anyone know if that's a supported Sitecore configuration?  Has anyone done it or have any gotchas that they can share?

Comment: Supported or not - its likely that setup will break your license. Each IIS instance will count as a Prod license. Its also a bad idea because each application will try to write to the same locations for things like log files, cache, temp files etc...

Comment: I am trying to gather some information.  My first thought is that this will have race conditions with /data/** file writes i.e. log4net etc and need to be customized to support such config.  Assuming client has enough licenses here, other things may break as well.  @Richard, thank you for chiming in.

Comment: You need a license for each IIS site. Also it pings home to Sitecore. If your license does not support it, they will be calling. Take it from a guy who got the call. :)

Comment: It should be technically possible. As an edge case, I do not believe it is a scenario that Sitecore would test against, so I would expect it is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, Sitecore does not recommend this, Some issues you might run into :

1. If your site have access to master Database and tries to update items, these updates will not be synced between all the Multi IIS sites because each IIS site will have its own inconsistent memory cache.
2. Each IIS site will have its own Sitecore memory cache of item/media content, You will end up with inconsistent sitecore cache again when Content gets published from CM -> CD, as not all IIS site will be able to clear and refresh its Sitecore memory, unless you have custom remote event implementation that clears the cache on each Site.
3. Possible log files locks when each IIS site tries to access the same log files and each one waits for the other to finish, this could cause major performance issues.

This link from Sitecore [SDN](https://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Multiple%20IIS%20Sites.aspx) talks about this subject, I could not find any newer article about this, But i think the SDN link information still valid for the latest Sitecore releases